# is it possible to put the controls components on each other?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

In short, I know that the wxWidgets allows arranging the controls components like that:

[image]

But I don't know whether it's also allowed to arrange the controls components as follow:

[image]

Note: that pictures are just preview pictures created by `.net`.

**Is it possible to arrange the controls components like the second picture (put the controls components on each other), and How?**

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Of course not, because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Just put them on the parent window as you normally would. The Win32 API certainly supports control overlap.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: but does wxWidgets itself support overlap?

Comment: Like I said, try it. It will only take 5 minutes.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I found some information talking about overlaps that say wxWidgets doesn't support overlaps. [src1](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=40587), [src2](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=24489). Is that right?

Comment: "but does wxWidgets itself support overlap?" - there are two very easy ways to find out. 1) Read the documentation. 2) Just try it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Please tell me which portion in the documentation do you want me I read? The documentation is big!

Comment: @Lion King why is the documentation being "big" a problem? Did you expect an instant answer? I would expect to spend a few days reading the docs (if not more) and playing with code as I learned. Or is that (actually reading docs from start to finish) no longer a thing?

Comment: Big documentation is a feature.  The difference between an expert and a beginner is the expert reads the documentation, over and over again, every day.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, wxWidgets doesn't guarantee that overlapped child windows will work correctly. Some native toolkits may support it, others may not, so it's just simpler to say that it's not supported -- especially because I've never heard of a good reason to use them.

Comment: Thanks, But @JesperJuhl said there are two ways to do that, are those ways not guaranteed too?